# How to write boolean value without using if statements

Tags: javascript, boolean

How do I apply an age discount in javascript without using the if/else statement?

I want to apply a discount for a service if someone is over the age of 21. So I need to write in javascript if age is over 21 it is true and if age is below 21 it is false.

How do I do this without using the if/else statement?

Comment: What stops you from using the if/else statement? If you really need to do it without an if/else statement you can try to utilize lazy evaluation to achieve this

Comment: use ternery operator

Comment: There are [logical operators](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#binary_logical_operators) and the [conditional (ternary) operator](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#conditional_ternary_operator). A discount can also be computed by multiplying some value with the appropriate boolean. Which of these options have you tried so far? Why are `if` statements not an option? Which boolean do you pick if the age is exactly 21?

Comment: `(age > 21 && discount) || 0`

Answer (score 1):

To set a boolean value, you can simply perform a logical test:

```js
var discount = age > 21
```

For other return values, use the Conditional / ternary operator which has the following syntax:

> condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

It can be used along the lines of the following:

```js
var discount = age > 21 ? "you have a discount" : "you don't have a discount";
```

See more on MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ternary` operator and get the discount. And use the discount for further processing.

```js
const getDiscount = age => age > 21 ? 5 : 0;

const price = 100;
let discountedPrice = (price - (getDiscount(22) * price / 100));
console.log('age > 21: ', discountedPrice);

discountedPrice = (price - (getDiscount(21) * price / 100));
console.log('age <= 21: ', discountedPrice);
```